# Check for python script restrictions before execution

Tags: python, security, static-analysis

I am looking forward a tools that will restrict python scripts by checking the use of commands like remove or modify files, open ports, ...

The goal is to implement a share place for python scripts without having to the user to open and understand the script before running it.

It is easy on linux using a very low privileges user, but on windows OS i can't...

Is there a restriction possible?

Comment: What if malicious commands activate only in some specific circumstances?

Comment: I am looking forward to restrict some basic actions to a python script like writing in a file or reading outside defined folders or executing scripts. More a static analysis...